# Cannot Attach MonoDevelop 5.9.6 to iOS 9.3.5

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

iOS device is not showing in Attach to Process window after following the instructions on Unity [website](https://docs.unity3d.com/420/Documentation/Manual/Debugger.html) for attaching MonoDevelop debugger to iOS. build & run, wait for app to start on device, stop xCode, open app on device, ensure device and computer running MonoDevelop are on same network, set MonoDevelop to Attach to Process.

Spec:
MacBook Pro Late 2013 - El Capitan 10.11.5
iPhone 5S (ME307LL/A) - iOS 9.3.5
MonoDevelop-Unity 5.9.6
Unity 5.4.1f1

Here are images of the options selected:

[image: Unity Preferences Window with options selected]
[image: Unity Build Settigs Window with options selected]
[image: Unity Player Settings Inspector with options selected]
[image: MonoDevelop Attach to Process option selected]
[image: MonoDevelop Attach to Process Window]

Comment: I have just answered an similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684910/unity-debugging-for-android-devices/42926397#42926397 Here is the solution:
Close unity but keep monodevelop ,then run debug in monodevelop , you will see device list in "Attach to Process" dialog. Hope it helps you!