# Unity debugging for android devices

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm having a hard time getting breakpoint debugging working for unity with and android device.  I've tried with both visual studio code and monodevelop.

**In android:**

I have successfully done all the steps outlined here for getting android connected over wifi in tcpip mode: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AttachingMonoDevelopDebuggerToAnAndroidDevice.html
[image]

**In unity**

In build settings I have "development build" and "script debugging" checked.  When I build and run, it programs my device just fine over wifi. 
[image: Android build settings]

**For monodevelop**

I try debugging with "attach to process" but it only finds the Unity Editor. 
[image] Lots of people have the same problem:https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/attaching-monodevelop-debugger-to-an-android-device.245814/
Down at the bottom, people are figuring out that multicast settings were the issue.  I have a linksys router, and I've ensured that security->filter multicast is unchecked.  Is there anything else I have to do here to get multicast to work?

Since monodevelop wasn't working, I tried with vscode

**For VS code**

I added the plugin to an empty project as described here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/unity

When I try debugging with vscode I get the error "Could not find target name 'Android Player'. Is it running?"
[image]

I also wanted to see which processes I could select but when I try running "Unity Attach Debugger" from the command palette, I get this error: "command 'attach.attachToDebugger' not found"
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling big time trying to attach a debugger to Android Unity build on either Emulated or physical device. I've tried Monodevelop, VS, and JetBrains Rider. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can debug my app easily using over USB, and In Visual Studio, I go under Debug -> Attach Unity Debugger and select my device. Have you tried debugging over USB?

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I've encountered the `Could not find target name 'Android Player'. Is it running?` message in Visual Studio Code when my laptop and the Android device I'm trying to debug were (accidentally) not connected to the same wifi network.

Connecting them to the same network got things working again. So that's an easy thing to check. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also got the problem today.

Your front steps are correct. Problem is "Attach to Process".

After app run on android device, close unity but keep monodevelop, then click the run button(or menu Run | Attach to Process) of monodevelop. Now u can see device list in the dialog.

It works for me. I found the solution from the thread u mentioned

[#15 manuelpeirone's answer](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/attaching-monodevelop-debugger-to-an-android-device.245814/#post-2894264)